# Use `purrr::map` with k-means

Tags: r, purrr

I thought that this

```
 kmeans(x = matrix(1:50, 5), centers = 2, iter.max = 10)
```

Could be written as:

```
matrix(1:50, 5) %>% 
map( ~kmeans(x = .x, centers = 2, iter.max = 10))

Error in sample.int(m, k) : 
  cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'
```

But the second does not work. How do I use `kmeans` in combination with `purrr::map()`?

Comment: Why do you need `map` here? `matrix(1:50, 5) %>% kmeans(., centers = 2, iter.max = 10)`.  A `matrix` is a `vector` with dim attributes.  When you do `map`, it goes through each single observation.

Comment: @akrun because in my original example I have several matrixes (scaled, with/without certain variables,etc.), and I would like to compare the results of the clustering against each other.

Comment: Not sure I get it.  If you have several matrices in a `list`, then `map` can be applied

Comment: Your approach would work if it is in a `list` i.e. `list(matrix(1:50, 5), matrix(51:100, 5)) %>% map( ~kmeans(x = .x, centers = 2, iter.max = 10))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `matrix`, by itself is a `vector` with dim attributes.  So, when we directly apply `map` on the `matrix`, it goes through the each of the individual elements.  Instead, place it in a `list`

```
list(matrix(1:50, 5) ) %>% 
         map( ~kmeans(x = .x, centers = 2, iter.max = 10))
```

Note that for a single `matrix`, we don't need `map`

```
 matrix(1:50, 5) %>% 
      kmeans(., centers = 2, iter.max = 10)
```

It becomes useful when we have a `list` of `matric`es

```
list(matrix(1:50, 5), matrix(51:100, 5)) %>% 
            map( ~kmeans(x = .x, centers = 2, iter.max = 10))
```